# How to set a child window's title

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

class MyApplication(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "Root Window"
        self.bind("<1>", self.showChild)

    def showChild(self):
        child = Toplevel(self)
        child.title = "This is the CHILD window"

app = MyApplication()
app.mainloop()
```

The child window's title is invariably set to `"Root Window"`. I can't figure out how to set the child window's title. I've also tried `child.wm_title = "This is the CHILD window"` to no avail. The docs at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ and http://www.tkdocs.com/ seem a bit outdated and haven't helped at all.

How do I set a Toplevel widget's title to something other than it's master's title??

Note: I'm pretty sure this is irrelevant, but I'm using Python 3.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the title with the `.title()` method,
instead of treating it as an attribute.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MyApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Root Window")
        self.bind("<1>", self.showChild)

    def showChild(self, event=None):
        self.top = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.top.title("This is the CHILD window")

app = MyApplication()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: @JoelCornett It would makes sense for it to be an attribute, so you don't have to beat yourself up too much (^_-). Maybe you will benefit from the [NMTech tkinter reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/) . It is one of my favorite sources, and you can't have too many.